# whole page affected by hover effect

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hover, visited

As the title says, I got a hover effect for my links but the whole page is affected for some reason.

This is my style

```
a:hover, :visited, :active, :hover
{
color:#fff;
text-shadow: -1px 1px 8px #ffc, 1px -1px 8px #fff;
text-decoration: none;
color: #009933;
text-shadow: none;
-webkit-transition: 500ms linear 0s;
-moz-transition: 500ms linear 0s;
transition: 500ms linear 0s;
outline: 0 none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3qpbv5fo/

By the way, while you're at it. Is my code readable so far? would you get what I was doing if you had to continue building the website? Just for me to get better.

Comment: `a:hover, :visited, :active, :hover` is the same as `a:hover, *:visited, *:active, *:hover` ... so it impacts everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're saying `:hover` among others with no element before it, so it refers to everything.

It's not sufficient to select the `a` element in the first selector only, if you put a comma between things, they get treated as completely separate selectors. So `a:hover, :hover` for example would be read as `a:hover` and `*:hover`.

See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp) for a guide on how to style links correctly.

Comment: alright thanks i saw it on w3schools but i saw it in a different example someone who did it only with commas. i might oversaw something. Another thing before i open another topic. Do you know by any chance a method to properly make a layout work on every resolution?

If i look at my site now on my 1920/1080 res. monitor my FB and tumbler links are messed up.. i keep having this problem. Know any "global" solution to this? google doesnt really help.

Comment: @PatrickHunter You are talking about responsive web design. Basically, you'll need to recognize the pixel dimensions of the browser window and then style accordingly, and you can have multiple styles for multiple screen width options. You can also utilize percentage widths and other stuff. But google responsive web design tutorial and you'll find a lot of stuff, like this https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/ .

Answer (score 0):

Remove `:hover` because it is applying the effect to every possible element, ID and class on the page. Your `a:hover` is sufficient and will apply the effect on all hovered links.

Answer (score 0):

you have to prefix `:hover` , `:visited` ... etc with a specific tag or it will effect the whole page.

do this instead

```
 a:hover
{
color:#fff;
text-shadow: -1px 1px 8px #ffc, 1px -1px 8px #fff;
text-decoration: none;
color: #009933;
text-shadow: none;
-webkit-transition: 500ms linear 0s;
-moz-transition: 500ms linear 0s;
transition: 500ms linear 0s;
outline: 0 none;
}
```

You can't have `a:visited` and `a:active` have the same CSS as your `a:hover`  because it won't work right. You need to make a seperate block of CSS for these. `a:hover` will effect all your link elements, even the visited ones.

Answer (score 0):

you use `:hover`  2 times in your css that mess up your code. you should omit last `:hover` in order to work your code correctly

Comment: This is not the real problem; See @PlantTheldea's comment under the question